# Getting exactly one element or raising exception with lxml xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The xpath() function in lxml normally returns a list of elements.

If I have an XPath which I expect to return exactly one element, what's the nicest way to:

- Check that one element is returned or else raise an exception, and:
- Get that element (as opposed to a one-element list)?

I'm really looking for the analogue of SQLAlchemy's one() function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
try:
    (element,) = tree.xpath('//xpath/selector')
except ValueError:
    raise InvalidSelector()
    # happened because the list was either empty or contained multiple elements
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could unpack a list against a tuple.

Comment: really nice and simple solution