# How to get first element from lxml using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, libxml2

Minimal example:

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: etree.fromstring('<who>syslogd</who>').xpath('/who/text()')

Out[2]: ['syslogd']
```

currently I'm using helper function:

```
def safe_xpath_one(tree: Element, xpath: str) -> Union[Element, None]:
    res = tree.xpath(xpath)
    if res:
        return res[0]
```

Here I then need to check first element from result which is additional. Is there direct way of specifying that I want the first and only first element?

P.S.: I think I got too much used to bs4's `soup.select_one`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615366/getting-exactly-one-element-or-raising-exception-with-lxml-xpath is there but again, I don't want to raise and handle error. It should return result or None

Comment: You want the same example of that answer but without throw exception?

Comment: Kind of. Yes. Just wanted to make sure if we have tree.xpath_one similiar to soup.select_one.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first element from an `lxml` object using `xpath`, you can use the [0] index operator after your `xpath` query. For example, if you have an `lxml` object called root, you could use the following code to get the first element matching the `xpath` query `//p`:

```
first_element = root.xpath('//p')[0]
```

This would return the first `p` element in the `lxml` object.

Another way to get the first element matching an `xpath` query is to use the `find()` method instead of `xpath()`. For example, you could use the following code to get the first p element in the `lxml` object:

```
first_element = root.find('//p')
```

This will return the first element that matches the `xpath` query, rather than returning a list of matching elements. You can then access the element's properties and attributes using standard dot notation, like so:

```
print (first_element.text)
```

Comment: I didn't know root.find does the root.xpath_one. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work. `etree.fromstring('<who>syslogd</who>').find('/who/text()')` or `'./who/text()'` doesn't work.

Comment: This worked. I had to change the minimal example. `etree.fromstring('<xml><who>syslogd</who></xml>').findtext('./who')`

Comment: This, however do not support full xpath spec so not so useful for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer but, this is how I'm currently doing

```
from lxml import etree
from functools import partial

def get_xpath_one(tree, xpath):
    res = tree.xpath(xpath)
    if res:
        return res[0]

tree = etree.fromstring('<who>syslogd</who>')
xpath_one = partial(get_xpath_one, tree)
res = xpath_one('/who/text()')

Out: 'syslogd'
```